# Python-flask extracting values from a POST request to REST API

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to extract values from a JSON payload by POST request:

**Question 1:**
What is a better way to get the data?

*First Way?*

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.data
        return test
```

*or Second Way?*

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = json.loads(request.json)
        return test
```

**Question 2:**
How do I get a specific value?

Given the json payload is:

```
{ "test": "hello world" }
```

I tried doing code below, but does not work.

```
#way1
return request.data["test"]

#error message: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

#way2
test["test"]

#error message: TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: "does not work" doesn't tell us much.  _How_ doesn't it work?  Do you get the wrong result?  No result at all?  An error message?

Comment: try `test = request.get_json(force=True)`

Comment: @PJSantoro So i would do it your way, but I how do I select a specific value given the json {"test:"test"} let's say I want to get the value of test

Comment: Your post is still unclear.  When, exactly, do you get `TypeError: expected string or buffer`?  Does it happen on the `json.loads()` call, or when you do `test["test"]`, or somewhere else?

Comment: It's not _my way_ it is the **way the Flask API recommends**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are posting JSON to a flask endpoint you should use:

[**request.get_json()**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

A very important API note:

> By default this function will return None if the mimetype is not application/json but this can be overridden by the force parameter

Meaning... either make sure the mimetype of the **POST** is *application/json* **OR** be sure to set the `force` option to `true`

A good design would put this behind:

[**request.is_json**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.is_json) like this:

```
@app.route('/post/', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    if request.is_json:
        data = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(data)
    else:
        return jsonify(status="Request was not JSON")
```

Comment: so how do I extract a specific value (Question 2)

Comment: JSON is a combination of nested Python dicts & lists, so `data["test"]` would give you the test key if the main JSON passed into the endpoint had a test key.